# recursive sql mathematics in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the last three children of my parent. Currently the statement reads:

```
SELECT * 
from replies 
order by rID,rValue
```

Because rValue signifies the reply mechanism a null rValue means that is the parent. To allow replies to replies rValue goes x to x.999999 and I was hoping there is some way to retrieve the last three results for each parent. Please hit me up if any further clarification is required.

**EDIT:** Lets say a limit of 30 thread per page and a maximum of 1000replies per thread would it be a huge strain on the DB just to get all the results then cycle through to the last 3 of each?

Comment: [MySQL recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345909/mysql-recursion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need common table expression and recursive queries. Take a look at your RDBMS if it supports them.