# MYSQL Query for getting complete parent history from a child id

Tags: mysql, parent-child

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345909/mysql-recursion)

I am trying to get the complete parent information from a child id in a single query. Is it possible?

example :

```
    id  |  ts_name  |  parent_id
    1  |  admin  |  0
    2  |  user  |  0
    3  |  card  |  0
    4  |  pin  |  0
    5  |  venkat  |  0
    7  |  admin_sub  |  1
    18  |  admin_sub2  |  7
    19  |  admin_sub2.1  |  18
    23  |  admin_sub1  |  7
    27  |  admin_sub3  |  7
    30  |  ghgfh  |  26
    37  |  vbnvbn  |  7
    38  |  add_sub_1  |  1
    41  |  admin_sub2.2.1  |  19
    42  |  admin_sub2.1.1.1  |  20
    43  |  admin_sub2.1.1.1  |  19
```

So what I am trying to get is

when I give child id = 19
it should return: 18,7,1

How to do that?

Comment: @ShehzadBilal: I think it is possible with recursive joins

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a function in plsql language on the sql server (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL), I don't know the syntax well, but overall algorith would look like this:

```
function getParents(id):
    returns varchar(1000);
    IS result varchar(1000);
    begin
        while (id ! = 0)
            id = getParent(id);
            result = id + ', ';

        removeLastComma(result);
        return result;
    end

function getParent(parent):
    returns varchar(20);
    IS result varchar(20)
    begin
        select id into result from example_table where parent_id = parent
        return result
    end

removeLastComma(string):
     // cut last two characters of the string
     // return processed string
```

pl/sql tutorial: http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-functions.htm

Probably it won't work as a copy-paste solution but I hope it will be a useful starter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be done in MySQL without either changing your table structure, or performing a number of queries.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345944/574303