# MySQL recursion - retrieve all subelements

Tags: mysql, recursion

5 and have the following scenario:

I have a database table with two columns: `id(int)`, `parentId(int)`.

Lets say my data looks like this

```
id  parentId
1   null
2   1
3   1
4   3
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   6
```

Now I would like to write a query which list all elements which have a specific element as ancestor. How can this be done?

For example I want all elements that have 4 as ancestor; `6,7,8`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql php question get parent id recrusive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006974/mysql-php-question-get-parent-id-recrusive)

Comment: Reformatted for code, but there are sections that don't make sense: it looks like there is text missing before `5 and have the following`?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345909/mysql-recursion

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/560648

Comment: A fully recursive query is not possible in MySQL using a single query. You can simulate it for a specified number of levels using self-joins, but a generalized single-query solution isn't possible. Other DBMSs have a "connect by prior" type thing which does allow single-query recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is an example of an [adjacency list model](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm) of hierarchical data. This has well known limitations, including making it impossible to write a single query that does what you want. (You can do a single query by imposing a depth limit, but it's painful.)

A better structure for this would be a [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). There's a nice article [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) on how the nested set model works, including plenty of SQL code for implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL lacks the hierarchical features other RDBMS have such as MSSQL **common table expressions** (CTE) and Oracle's **connect by** which make working with adjacency lists simple and efficient. As a consequence you'll have to do something like the following:

[Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem/5291159#5291159)

Hope this helps :)